# Where does systemd-resolve get my ISP DNS?

Tags: dns

I set a static IP and DNS through the netplan `nameservers` configuration. I set my LAN DNS and the cloudfare DNS in both IPV4 and IPV6 notation. As so:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [10.0.0.120/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.110,1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1,"2606:4700:4700::1111","2606:4700:4700::1001"]
        search: [michigan]
     access-points:
        "*******":
          password: "*******"
```

Yet `systemd resolve --status` reports the DNS as :

```
   DNS Servers: 10.0.0.110
                  1.1.1.1
                  1.0.0.1
                  2606:4700:4700::1111
                  2606:4700:4700::1001
                  2001:nnnn:0:400b::12
                  2001:nnnn:0:400c::12
```

`resolv.conf` is linked as so:

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

And `resolv.conf` content is :

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1111
nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1001
nameserver 2001:nnnn:0:400b::12
nameserver 2001:nnnn:0:400c::12
search michigan
```

dnsmasq ?

```
 # dpkg -l *dnsmasq* 
 Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
 | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
 |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
 ||/ Name             Version       Architecture Description
 +++-================-=============-============-============================================
 un  dnsmasq          <none>        <none>       (no description available)
 ii  dnsmasq-base     2.80-1ubuntu1 amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
 un  dnsmasq-base-lua <none>        <none>       (no description available)
```

I don't want my ISP's DNS involved at all. Does this mean that my ISP DNS will be logging my requests anyway? Perhaps not, perhaps we use only the first DNS to respond but I don't know that. And I would like to understand what's going on.

I can set a firewall rule to deny the ISP DNS and all seems well enough, but is there any issue I should be thinking of there?

Comment: You'll get the ISP's DNS servers from the dhcp request. You may be able to set `DNS=` in the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`... but I don't know if that will eliminate the ISP's DNS. And DNS requests are made in parallel, not first in the list, so any DNS server could answer. You may need to use VPN. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I've updated the question to include my netplan configuration. It is for static IP, sets dhcp to no. What effect does that have?

Comment: Are you using server or desktop Ubuntu? If desktop, why are you using netplan (esp to connect to a wireless network)?

Comment: @heyenna Desktop. I prefer netplan. I am not particularly mobile and find configuration to new networks simple enough. Would network-manager get around this DNS issue? If so then how does it do it?

Comment: It's @heynnema :-) And... **nobody** prefers netplan in a desktop environment, esp if the machine is portable, or is used to connect to various wired/wireless networks. There are three different symlinks for /etc/resolv.conf, and one may work better/different than the other. Show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and the `DNS=` entry I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @heynnema Oops. Sorry. Well I'm here to prove your **nobody** rule an over-generalisation (one of the issues of our time - sigh) , I like to tinker, and dislike magical appleish features. I've updated the question to your requests. I must be off for a while now.

Comment: Interesting... too many DNS servers. Just for fun, reset your /etc/resolv.conf symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, reboot, and lets see what's changed. Do you/are you intending to use VPN?

Comment: @heynnema  There is no file '/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` in my edition of Ubuntu 19.04. I have a high speed internet connection and find that my VPN provider (expressvpn) is much much slower. Do you have an opinion on my firewall solution?

Comment: It would be instructive to see if you have any DNS leaks with/without VPN... go to dnsleak.com or dnsleaktest.com to find out. VPN will always be slower than without VPN.

Comment: @heynnema All listings are Cloudfare but the judgment of the sites is that the DNS could be leaking. Is that because the Cloudfare IPs are not associated with my ISP IPs? Or is there some other clue?

Comment: Did you test with VPN up? It means that one or more DNS servers are reachable outside of the secure tunnel, and any/all of them could be logging you. Since you like to tinker... I'll leave the lesson for you to solve :-)

Comment: @heynnema VPN up gives a different mixed list rather than the uniforn 'cloudfare'listing without VPN. And of course my external IP is different.  I've read that a leak listing is not by itself evidence of a leak but rather a flag to investigation. We are to ask "Do you trust these guys?" Thanks for the help and for the tips. I'll tinker on. I still don't know how systemd gets these DNS.

Comment: Show me `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*`. When VPN is up, a DNS leak is a leak that needs to be fixed, if part of your goal is no tracking/logging, and security.

Comment: @heynnema Added to question. My goal is to understand what's going on. I am not comfortable with the ISP DNS being forced like this. I don't like the idea of being tracked through DNS but it's not a mission critical concern or the driving motivation here.

Comment: DNS operation on Ubuntu 18.xx and 19.xx is black magic. I don't think **anybody** can tell you/me exactly how it works. Sure, there's things that we can check, but that can take time too. For tinkering purposes, would you consider (at least temporarily) switching to using NetworkManager? It requires a simple /etc/netplan/*.yaml change to do that, and then we can see what works or doesn't. Netplan has some black magic things also, and this would eliminate a netplan issue.

Comment: @heynnema Sure. Unfortunately on the test machine I have lost the nm-applet which is how I would configure the ipv6 DNS IPs. The resolv.conf has the ISP's ipv6 addresses but I'd expect that in the absence of anything from my side. I don't want to mess up any of my other machines so I'll set up a VM sometime this weekend. Unless you know how to restore the nm-applet.

Comment: We can test without ipv6 for now. We just want to watch the dns stuff in action without netplan. You can reinstall `network-manager-gnome` (19.04...check synaptic for your version) and it has nm-applet. Do you know how to change the /etc/netplan/*.yaml file for networkmanager?